# multiple conditions with mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to add a third condition to this syntax so that the the S139a field becomes invisible.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 80px; visibility: visible">S139a:</div>
<div style="float: left;">@if (Model.xyz == 0)
{@Html.Raw("No")}
else
{@Html.Raw("Yes")}
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: You should add more code than that.  What is the `S139a` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code that displays the `S139a` field in an `if`, then deal with displaying the "No" or "Yes".

```
@if (Model.SomeProperty == false)
{
    // Display the S139a field.  Then check xyz.
    if (Model.xyz == 0)
    { 
        @Html.Raw("No")
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.Raw("Yes")
    }
}
```

I'm making some assumptions, since I really don't know what the `S139a` field is, or what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: Why the -1?  Seems like a valid answer to me.

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to ignore downvotes at this point.  At least tell a person _why_ you're giving their question/answer a downvote!

Comment: @Gomer because it isn't answer on OP's question. Where did you get that outer `if`? Why not inner? And where third condition?

Comment: He wanted to show "Yes", "No" or hide the element.  It sounds like he knows what condition evaluate to display this element, so I provided a solution.  The outer does the check to see if he's needing to display the element.  If the inside block of code runs, it's because he needs to display the element.  So display the element, and do the "Yes", "No" check.